# How can i get pointer's address from other application without Cheat Engine?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, visual-c++, function-pointers

I want to change or read the pointer's value which is in other program.But i need to know pointer's address.Can i get the address without Cheat Engine and how can i do that ? In the youtube/google/facebook they are using Cheat Engine to know the address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  DWORD pointer = 0x006DFEF8;  // I learned this address from Cheat Engine.
  DWORD pid;
  int deger;
  char program_isim[100];

  std::cin >> program_isim;

  HWND program = FindWindow(0, program_isim);
  if (program == 0) {
    std::cout << program_isim << ",bulunamadi." << std::endl;
  } 
   else {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(program, &pid);
    HANDLE hand = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
    while (1) {
           ReadProcessMemory(hand, (void*)pointer, &deger, sizeof(deger), 0);
           std::cout << deger << std::endl;
              }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While spacing and indentation is irrelevant for the compiler, it's very important for humans attempting to read and understand your code. Please edit your question to add at least some (consistent) indentation, and maybe some empty lines to split the code into "paragraphs".

Comment: You would have to implement similar mechanics as Cheat Engine does to find out the adress you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat Engine is a disassembler and debugger.  You can find pointers using both of these features, but everything is easiest when using a debugger at runtime.  It allows you to set "break on read" and "break on write" breakpoints.  The "find what accesses" function of Cheat Engine is just using read breakpoints and logging the addresses where the breakpoint is hit.

Cheat Engine will always be the best way to find pointers.  Can you find a pointer via static analysis?  Yes you can but it will be more difficult.

You can replicate Cheat Engine's behavior by writing your own program which registers itself as a debugger with the Windows API and set breakpoints on the target process.

But the reason you can't use Cheat Engine is because the game has anticheat that detects your debugger, it will also detect your debugger you write so this is not the solution.

The solution is to bypass the anticheat and then just use Cheat Engine as normal.